# What is a Cohoist in scalaz?

Tags: scala, scalaz, comonad

The [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) defines a [`Cohoist`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/ComonadTrans.scala#L11):

```
  trait Cohoist[F[_[_], _]] extends ComonadTrans[F] {
    def cohoist[M[_], N[_]: Comonad](f: M ~> N): F[M, ?] ~> F[N, ?]
  }
```

where `ComonadTrans` is defined:

```
 trait ComonadTrans[F[_[_], _]] {
   def lower[G[_]: Cobind, A](a: F[G, A]): G[A]
 }
```

The question is how to treat this type? Can someone give an explanation in a few words or give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComonadTrans` isn't really important to understanding `cohoist`, which is similar to a higher-order version of map.

`map` can be reformulated, by flipping the arguments around, as

```
[A, B](A => B) => (F[A] => F[B])
```

In other words it lifts a function into `F`. `~>` is just

```
F ~> G
[A]F[A] => G[A]
```

With that you can expand the signature of `cohoist`

```
[M[_], N[_]: Comonad]([A]M[A] => N[A]) => ([A]F[M, A] => F[N, A])
```

(the two `A`s cannot be combined and pulled to the initial tparam list; I don't want to go into detail here beyond saying "that would not work")

**So just like map, it lifts a function (M to N transformer) into `F`, making an "F of M" to "F of N" transformer.**